# matrix norm that is invariant through a change of basis

Tags: math, linear-algebra, algebra

I am looking for matrix norms that would be invariant through a change of basis. I know only about the Frobenius norm, which satisfy this condition as it can be expressed as a function of the eigenvalues of the matrix only. Are there other norms like that? If so, what is their geometrical interpretation?

Comment: Sounds like a question for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I asked the question there, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on wikipedia at [Matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) you'll find a variety of answers, including the Frobenius norm.